# Project data with children and grandchildren entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to get data in a suitable format for an api

What I would like is

```
Place
--Rating1
---RatingImage1.1
---RatingImage1.2
---UserName
---UserId
--Rating2
---RatingImage2.1
---RatingImage2.2
---UserName
---UserId
```

In a nutshell im trying to fetch a place, with its ratings(and rating images), with the names of the users who did the rating given the googlePlaceId

Tried this but it goes and does some circular fetching where once it fetches the user it then fetches the user rating and the response becomes massive

```
context.Places
            .Include(x => x.Ratings.Select(y => y.User))
            .Include(x => x.Ratings.Select(c => c.RatingImages))
            .Single(x => x.GooglePlaceId == googlePlaceId);
```

I think projection or linq joins must be the way, but i havent had any success yet.

here are my POCOS

Place Poco

```
public class Place
    {
        public Place()
        {
            Ratings = new List<Rating>();
            Favourites = new List<Favourite>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string GooglePlaceId { get; set; }


        public  ICollection<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
        public  ICollection<Favourite> Favourites { get; set; }

    }
```

Rating POCO

```
 public class Rating
    {
        public Rating()
        {
            RatingImages = new List<RatingImage>();

        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public float RatingValue { get; set; }
        public string RatingComment { get; set; }


        public int PlaceId { get; set; }
        public Place Place { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public AspNetUser User { get; set; }

        public  ICollection<RatingImage> RatingImages { get; set; }

    }
```

User POCO

```
public partial class AspNetUser
    {

public string UserName { get; set; }
public string Id { get; set; }

// the rest of the fields are omitted
}
```

Comment: [I explained to you why this happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36235997/get-the-username-on-a-navigation-property-using-include#comment60105168_36235997). Why do you ignore what was explained and asked there? You should have edited the original question.

Comment: @gert, I probably should have worded the initial question better, I'm hoping this is a better attempt. Whilst I understand that include isn't the right way. I'm looking for an answer as to how to do it, as even with projections I wasn't getting close enough

Answer (score 0):

Although you've omitted the definition of AspNetUser, I'm guessing it has a navigation property back to Ratings.  Is this required anywhere else in your application?  It won't affect the structure of your database, and removing it would allow your projection to work exactly as you've got it here.  You'd still be able to display all ratings by a single user using a separate query - you've got to optimise for your most common scenario though.

Comment: Thats interesting, I have included ICollection<Rating> Ratings in AspNetUser as i wanted to establish an FK relationship. (this seems common from what ive seen, i.e id + entity in one class and the collection in the other... In my context i need modelBuilder.Entity<Rating>().HasRequired(x => x.User).WithMany(x => x.Ratings).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);